# Getting random element from a csv file

Tags: python, csv, random, python-3.x

I have a Csv file containing many words. I want to write a python3 code that get a word from this file randomly. Since object returned from`csv.reader(file)` has no length parameter and isn't indexed, I have no idea how to get a word by random.

```
spamReader = csv.reader(open('A3_words.csv', 'r'))
# something like:
# rnd = random.randrange(reader.length)
# word = reader[rnd]
```

I would appriciate any help.

## EDIT:

Every word is in a separated line like this:

```
when  
what  
make  
time
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code would produce a random string from the sample you've provided

```
import csv
import random

spamReader = csv.reader(open('A3_words.csv', 'r'))

data = sum([i for i in spamReader],[]) #To flatten the list
print(random.choice(data))
```

Comment: Oo I'm sorry. I will edit the question. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Since my csv file is small, there isn't much overhead reading whole file, but is there any way getting one element without reading it all?

Comment: I'm sorry for delay in approving and upvoting. Your answer worked well. Thank you.

Comment: @alireza thanks, BTW you cannot prevent it from reading the whole csv file.... however your code can be optimized but that's out of scope....